# How to do glDiscardFramebufferEXT in metal

Tags: metal, framebuffer

I need to port the `glDiscardFramebufferEXT()` OpenGL method to metal and I haven't found anything useful on the internet yet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Its functionality is in [MTLRenderPassDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrenderpassdescriptor):

> A MTLRenderPassDescriptor object contains a collection of attachments that are the rendering destination for pixels generated by a rendering pass. The MTLRenderPassDescriptor class is also used to set the destination buffer for visibility information generated by a rendering pass.

See especially members `{color/depth}Attachments.storeAction` and `{color/depth}.loadAction`. 
`MTLLoadActionDontCare` means ignoring.